# .NET Radbutton Click event not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, user-controls, telerik

I have a user control on which the button click event stopped firing even if I add a new button. It can be noted I'm using Telerik RadControls: RadButton specifically.

There's nothing special I'm doing to reference the elements:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="RadButton">
            </telerik:RadButton>
```

Codebehind:

```
    Protected Sub RadButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton1.Click
    Dim test As String = "string"
End Sub
```

There's also an ordinary  i have that doesn't fire either.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see any issue with your code. Try to add Response.Write("Hello") into click event and see what happen?

Comment: What do you mean stopped? Like no postback occurs? Are you setting a break point and it's not hitting it? That Click function won't actually do anything visible to your page..

Comment: For ordinary radio button, can you verify these two properties exists in the markup? OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: Have you contacted the Telerik support about this, if not why? if so what did they say?

Comment: I've found the problem, it's in my answer. It seems that validators on a different pageview in the form were preventing postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user control is in a `<telerik:RadPageView>` which is referenced by a `<telerik:RadTabStrip>`.

There is also another user control which consists of several input fields with RequiredFieldValidators and CompareValidator. Removing the validators seems to enable postback, so it was probably them causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the sintax is, but you don't seem to have an OnClick event attached. It should be something like this:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" OnClick="RadButton1_Click" runat="server" Text="RadButton">
</telerik:RadButton>
```